# link to a specific product in Zen cart

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to have products link in homepage that directly take to their respective single product page and also wanna be able to have a product details on a custom product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To link to any specific product You need to know its products_id. If You know it it's enough to put this in Your template:

```
<a href="<?php echo zen_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO,"products_id=$product_id_of_your_product");?>">My Great Product</a>
```

You'll have to be more elaborate on what You mean by product details.

--- EDIT
To find out product id navigate to Admin->Catalog->Categories & Products->(locate Your product)->ID is on the right side of product listing in column "ID".

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is actually what I am looking to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752767/zen-cart-i-would-like-to-query-from-a-specific-category-its-products-name-pric