# Zen cart: I would like to query from a specific category its products name, price, image, description, and attributes

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

I am using the following query:

```
<?php
 // retrieve products from database
 global $db;
$q1 = $db->Execute("select * from products");
$q1_items = array();
$q2_items = array();

while (!$q1->EOF){
$q1_items[] = $q1->fields;
$q1->MoveNext();
}
foreach ($q1_items as $item => $items) {
echo '<p><a href="index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id='. $items['products_id'] .'"><img src="images/'. $items['products_image'].'" alt="'. $items['products_name'].'" title="'. $items['products_name'].'" /></a>';
    echo ''.$items['products_price']. ''; ?>

<?php }
?>
```

The issue I am having is it doesn't not pull the product name and I would like to be able to query each product_description from TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION and Products_attributes.

Comment: Note that You asked for product attributes but You don't make use of them in Your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because products_name and products_description is in table products_description (or to be more specific in TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION), not in table products (TABLE_PRODUCTS).

To get all basic information (except attributes) You should execute following query:

```
$q = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ON(p.products_id = pd.products_id) WHERE language_id = " . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id']);
$items = array();
while(!$q->EOF) {
    // let's get all attribues for product
    $productInfo = $q->fields;
    $qattr = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . " WHERE products_id = " . (int)$q->fields['products_id']);
    $attr = array();
    while(!$qattr->EOF) {
        $attr[] = $qattr->fields;
        $qattr->MoveNext();
    }
    $productInfo['attributes'] = $attr;
    $items[] = $productInfo;
    $q->MoveNext();
}

// now let's output it
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<p><a href="index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id='. $item['products_id'] .'"><img src="images/'. $item['products_image'].'" alt="'. $item['products_name'].'" title="'. $items['products_name'].'" /></a>';
    echo $items['products_price'] . '</p>';
}
```

Note however that this code does **NOT** get products from specific category - it gets all products, even those that are deactivated. There are several ways to get products from specific category but they vary in performance. Unfortunately there's no best way to do this because it depends on the data. If the products You wish to retrieve belong to category with categories_id of 5 and it's their primary category it's enough to add to first query "WHERE master_categories_id = 5". But if the category is not master category for those products things get bit more complicated because We need to access products_to_categories table which causes performance hit for sites with many products. If You don't know/don't care about performance that much You can change first query to: (assuming that You already know categories_id of Your category):

```
$q = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ON(p.products_id = pd.products_id LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " p2c ON(p.products_id = p2c.products_id AND p2c.categories_id = YOUR_CATEGORY_ID) WHERE pd.products_id IS NOT NULL AND p2c.products_id IS NOT NULL AND language_id = " . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id']);
```

To get rid of inactive products execute

```
$q = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ON(p.products_id = pd.products_id LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " p2c ON(p.products_id = p2c.products_id AND p2c.categories_id = YOUR_CATEGORY_ID) WHERE products_status = 1 AND pd.products_id IS NOT NULL AND p2c.products_id IS NOT NULL AND language_id = " . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id']);
```

(Actually check on pd.products_id IS NOT NULL is not needed because We already check pd.language_id.)

---

EDIT Version without attributes

```
$q = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ON(p.products_id = pd.products_id) WHERE language_id = " . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id']);
$items = array();
while(!$q->EOF) {
    $items[] = $q->fields;
    $q->MoveNext();
}

// now let's output it
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<p><a href="index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id='. $item['products_id'] .'"><img src="images/'. $item['products_image'].'" alt="'. $item['products_name'].'" title="'. $items['products_name'].'" /></a>';
    echo $items['products_price'] . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have only one category with fewer than 10 items. I want to pull product details in order to use them in a one page design similar to http://www.squarespace.com/tour/overview/ I will try this asap and will let you know. thanks again.

Comment: no luck! no useful error, WARNING: An Error occurred, please refresh the page and try again.

Comment: If I can just have a simple JOIN between table_products and table_products_description I will be fine. I am able to query the products_name and products_description when I substitute $q1 = $db->Execute("select * from products") for $q1 = $db->Execute("select * from products_desciption"); If I can save the first query under $q1, the second under $q2, and finally output both under a join array or simply make $q1 = array $db->Execute("select * from products, products_description") or something clause.

Comment: Sorry, there were two typos in my example. I fixed them and checked that the code works. I also added example without fetching for attributes.